# Double summation without loop in R?

Tags: r, vectorization

Have been thinking to solve the double summation problem in an easy way. The equation is shown as :[image]

where i and j are two firms, and p,q are directors on the boards respectively.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You may have a look at the outer product, `%o%` or  `outer()`.

Answer (score 2):

```r
popu_p <- 1:3
popu_q <- 5:6
dia_dist_pq <- 1:6

# using outer()
sum(outer(popu_p, popu_q) * matrix(dia_dist_pq, length(popu_p), byrow = TRUE))
#> [1] 278

# compare answer to a loop
dia_dist_ij <- 0
pq <- 1
for(p in 1:length(popu_p)) {
  for(q in 1:length(popu_q)) {
    dia_dist_ij <- dia_dist_ij + popu_p[p] * popu_q[q] * dia_dist_pq[pq]
    pq <- pq + 1
  }
}
dia_dist_ij
#> [1] 278
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the comments. What if the length of p and q are unequal?  The `sum(outer(popu_p, popu_q) * matrix(dia_dist_pq, 3, byrow = TRUE))` seems not work if, for instance, p <- 1:3 and q<- 5:6.

Comment: You will need to apply some knowledge of matrix multiplication in that the dimensions of the two matrices need to conform. I have changed the example for unequal p and q and tried to make it more universal by inserting `length(popu_p)` as opposed to hard coding that dimension.